# Axios - HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, axios

I've to make a POST request to localhost:8080/api/session, sending email and password as x-www-form-urlencoded. In Postman, everything works, but trying two different solutions with Axios, I obtain `415-Unsopported Media Type`
First solution:

```
var request_url = url + request.path;
var params = new URLSearchParams();
params.append('email', 'example@example.com');
params.append('password', 'example');
axios.post(request_url, params)
.then(res => {
    console.log("ok")
})
.catch(error => {
  console.error(error)
})
```

Second solution:

```
const data = qs.stringify({
email: 'example@example.com',
password: 'example',
});

const headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8'
};


axios.post(
    'http://10.10.0.145/api/session',
    data,
    headers
  ).then(result => {console.log("ok")});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 1. You cant't use `URLSearchParams` for post data. 2. I don't know what `qs` means. But assuming it is a query string library, you should not use query string for post data. Just use plain object like `axios.post(url, { email: '123' }`.